# ubuntu 17.10 no sound

Tags: upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 17.10

I just upgraded my system from 17.04 to 17.10.
After the upgrade I have no sound on my system from any output (analog output or hdmi via gpu).

At the sound tab under settings no device is listed.

The lscpi outputs

```
> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM
> Registers (rev 07) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe
> Controller (x16) (rev 07) 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation
> Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) 00:14.2 Signal
> processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal
> subsystem (rev 31) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation
> Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31) 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel
> Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
> 00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port
> #17 (rev f1) 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) 00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation
> Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge:
> Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31) 00:1f.2
> Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
> 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev
> 31) 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
> 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2)
> I219-V (rev 31) 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro
> Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] (rev c7) 01:00.1
> Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device aaf0
> 04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
> NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
```

The aplay -l outputs

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and the inxi -F outputs

```
System:    Host: theodoruntu Kernel: 4.13.11+ x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.26.1
           Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASRock model: Z170 Pro4S serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: P7.30 date: 11/28/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-6700K (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           clock speeds: max: 4400 MHz 1: 4000 MHz 2: 4000 MHz 3: 4000 MHz 4: 4000 MHz 5: 4000 MHz
           6: 4000 MHz 7: 4000 MHz 8: 4000 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
           Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.5 )
           drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@59.96hz, 1920x1080@59.96hz
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 480 Graphics (AMD POLARIS10 / DRM 3.23.0 / 4.13.11+, LLVM 5.0.0)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.2
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device aaf0 driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Philips (or NXP) SPZ2000 Webcam [PixArt PAC7332] driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.11+
Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: d0:50:99:95:51:db
Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: N/A size: 500.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 97G used: 34G (37%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.5C mobo: N/A gpu: 36.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 308 Uptime: 22 min Memory: 3109.1/7927.9MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37
```

I have also installed pulse audio but it doesnt start...

I came across other posts on the internet where people have no sound on ubuntu 17.10 but no one posted a solution... Does anybody knows how to fix this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I accidentaly found that pulseaudio does not start on boot... If I start it manually everything works! Is there any proper solution?

Comment: you can post this as an answer. I just added pulseaudio to the startup applications list. Let's see, if this fixes the problem after the next boot

Comment: After I upgrade to 17.10 pulseaudio didn't want to start, so purged it with `sudo apt purge 'pulseaudio*'` and then I installed all the packages that were removed by that command again. All is working fine now.

Comment: I had this problem - Commenting out `load-module module-switch-on-connect` in /etc/pulse/default.pa worked for me when purging and reinstalling pulseaudio on its own didn't -- hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Linux kernel and install current Mesa driver, i had the same problem here with Radeon RX560 on Ubuntu 17.10, it works!
Mesa:
https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa
Kernel:
https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries