# Sound not working after upgrading to 17.10?

Tags: upgrade, sound

This looks like quite common problem. I found several threads on this, but none of those worked for me.

I tried removing and installing pulseaudio, unmuting everything from alsamixer, updated kernel and driver as said here [ubuntu 17.10 no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975715/ubuntu-17-10-no-sound), force relaoded alsa.

Here is the outcome of `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer HD Graphics 520
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at de000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at df310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at df32d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at df328000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at df32c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at df32b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: df200000-df2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d11 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: df100000-df1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: df000000-df0fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at df324000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pmc_core

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133
    Memory at df320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at df32a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at df215000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at df200000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at df214000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at df210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at df010000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

Comment: Also, I noted that there appears something like unix Fifo Sink when I try to increase or decrease volume using fn+f5/f6

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `uname -a`, `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'` (replaces the current `lspci` output in your question with more relevant info), `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for me: the problem was with chrome-remote-desktop that makes in .config/chrome-remote-desktop folder with wrong config for pulse
so the commands that i used was:

```
sudo apt-get purge chrome-remote-desktop
rm -v -rf chrome-remote-desktop
```

and then it work like a charm